# Resize Picture and Keep Aspect Ratio in Autohotkey GUI

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to have an image be 100% of the window width and keep it's aspect ratio while resizing an AutoHotKey GUI?

I have a simple GUI as follows:

```
Gui +Resize
Gui, Add, Picture, w440 h-1 vProductImage, default.png
Gui, Show, , MyApp
```

The closest thing I have been able to come to is `Anchor.ahk` http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/4105-control-anchoring-v4-for-resizing-windows/

Using it, I can have the image resized when the window is resized but it doesn't keep it's aspect ratio and gets deformed

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Dont know if it applies to your framework, but most browsers will auto figure out the correct param if you specify just the height, or just the width. Keeping the source aspect ratio.

Comment: This is not in a web browser. It is a Windows Desktop Application

Comment: Then it probably does not apply :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing I could come up with:

Assuming the picture is 440x350, is 85 pixels from the top of the app window (left:0)

```
GuiSize:
if(A_GuiWidth < A_GuiHeight)
{
    GuiControl, MoveDraw, ProductImage, % "w" . (A_GuiWidth - 20) . " h" . (350/440) * (A_GuiWidth - 20)
}
else
{
    GuiControl, MoveDraw, ProductImage, % "w" . (440/350) * (A_GuiHeight - 85) . " h" . (A_GuiHeight - 85)
}
return
```

(the 20 is for window padding)

Comment: I think that's probably along the lines of the way I'd do it, too.